# Moving Windows C++ project from Qt4 to 5 gives hundreds of seemingly unrelated compilation errors

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, visual-c++, com

I upgraded to Qt5/msvc2010 and am now trying to build a project using Qt Creator that was working fine with Qt4/msvc2008 (no source code has changed since it was working).

The project uses some COM elements to talk to external audio recording devices via an Olympus SDK.

What could cause all of these errors when everything was working fine before I upgraded to Qt5? To my knowledge none of the classes listed in these errors are actually used by my project.

I've tried including files that define the classes in question (e.g. ocidl.h for IEnumConnections) in every header file possible, even switching the order of includes to many different combinations to no avail.

```
e:\bp\mainwindow.h(21) : warning C4005: 'WINVER' : macro redefinition
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\sdkddkver.h(212) : see previous definition of 'WINVER'
e:\bp\mainwindow.h(25) : warning C4005: '_WIN32_WINNT' : macro redefinition
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\sdkddkver.h(197) : see previous definition of '_WIN32_WINNT'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(53) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IEnumConnections'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(53) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(53) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IEnumConnections'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(53) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(53) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(53) : error C2086: 'int IEnumConnections' : redefinition
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(53) : see declaration of 'IEnumConnections'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(59) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IConnectionPoint'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(59) : warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(65) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IEnumConnectionPoints'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(65) : warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(71) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IConnectionPointContainer'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(71) : warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(77) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IClassFactory2'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(77) : warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(83) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IProvideClassInfo'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(83) : warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(89) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IProvideClassInfo2'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\ocidl.h(89) : warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'interface' when no variable is declared
```

Full error listing is here: http://dpaste.com/1525608/

Comment: Quacks like macro trouble, something is whacking the symbol "interface".  Compile with /P to see what happened to it.

Comment: Try two-step upgrade. First, update to MSVC10, see if it works? If that works, try to upgrad to Qt 5. Does the first step work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The windows inclusion has been changed in Qt 5. You will need to include the `windows.h` after your `sdkddkver.h` inclusion.

Comment: I'm not actually including that file anywhere, neither is the Olympus SDK. Even totally leaving out the include path for the Windows SDK does not change anything. Somehow it still gets included (by MSVC compiler maybe?).

Comment: @bparker: something does include it, so you need to figure out what exactly. If you want us to help with this, please provide more code. Which windows headers exactly are you including?

Comment: It seems that windows.h was included somehow by including QMainWindow, so I had to move my COM header includes above that, now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving #include "windows.h" above all your other includes, and/or above every reference to olympus sdk.

Also do a full build clean.  Including deleting any Makefile, or Makefile.debug and your debug and release folders.

If that still doesn't fix it, turn of shadow building.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried all of your suggestions multiple times, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: This does not address the concern. It is true that there is a porting issue about windows.h being included at the top for certain math functions, etc, but that is not the case here.