# Missing window SDK header after switching for msvc2013 to 2015

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, sdk

I was using Qt 64 bits with msvc2013, everything was fine. I had to switch to msvc2015, and the related Qt and now I have several error of missing include

`sdkddkver.h` and `VerRsrc.h`

I found these two header in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include and if I copy them to my project directory, other include are missing.
I ended up with missing winapifamily.h and i cant find it anywhere

MSVC2013 Express is uninstalled
MSVC2015 Pro is installed
SDK 8.1 installed with debugging tool

Edit : additionnal info : compiler and debugger looks fine inside Qt, and it seems to use vcvarsall.bat correctly

Edit2 : Investigation continue
A really basic main compile but if I add another include, the error appears

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
//#include <QAbstract3DGraph>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *mw = new QMainWindow;
    QPushButton bouton("Hello world",mw);
    mw->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

If I uncomment `#include <QAbstract3DGraph>` I have the error

Edit 3 : If I have both msvc 2013 & 2015 installed it works, but it's not a good solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20805090/1938163

Comment: Make sure that everything including Qt was built with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I downloaded the msvc2015 qt version : qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015_64-5.7.0.exe. Also added an edit to my post with an additionnal info

Answer (score 0):

Just the other day, I had a similar problem after upgrading my Visual Studio build.

First, uninstall the Qt build for VS2013 and re-install the VS2015 edition of Qt.  You probably already did this.

With everything shut down, delete your local `%APPDATA%\QtProject` directory and all files and subfolders within it.  This is typically located in your user account as `c:\users\<your name>\appdata\roaming\QtProject`

By deleting my QtCreator settings in that folder, everything seemed to start working again.

Comment: Didnt work. To be sure, I uninstalled Qt, deleted folders in appdata and reinstalled Qt, still the same issue